# Rhombic Dodecahedron, Rhombic Tricontahedron, Rhombic Enneacontahedron, Rhombic X What shape?

Tags: geometry

## What Shape is this?

I know for a fact that it is not a Rhombic Enneacontahedron.

[image: rhombic]

Comment: Where is it located?

Comment: No Idea, but if I build one I will tell you.

Comment: @WillJagy apparently at the "The Doors" Guitarist's house. https://www.o2treehouse.com/honey-sphere

Comment: Thank you. It makes more sense that professionals did this. it is a very intricate project. I will look at the link more, see if there is some sort of identification of the people who designed it or built it.

Comment: I see, the designer is using the terminology of Buckminster Fuller, who described "geodesic domes" as an alternative in architecture. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckminster_Fuller  as well as  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_dome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that if you join each short rhombus diagonal with a segment, then erase all the original segments (boards), the result is one of the less symmetric Goldberg polyhedra, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_polyhedron under Class III, frequency (1,2)

This Goldberg polyhedron has 72 Faces, 140 Vertices, 210 Edges. Each edge comes from one rhombus (might not be perfect rhombuses) in the original structure, so that has 210 diamond shapes.  Should be 420 boards. Impressive.

I think it will let me load an image, but not as png format...

[image]

It's correct, I was able to outline two pentagons, with two neighboring hexagons each, the hexagons with edges in common as well.
[image]

Comment: From the information you gave me I found http://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=A200k5k6wD is the closest shape I can find; but I'm not sure it's possible to make this shape with FLAT rhombuses as opposed to 2 triangles. I'm going to mark this as accepted, and make a new question determining if this shape is even possible with rhombuses.

Comment: @GlassGhost it is NOT possible with all rhombuses. I could have emphasized that more.

Comment: @GlassGhost  the dodecahedron and the soccer ball are made with all regular sides. As soon as you get to the chamfered dodecahedron (42 sides) it is not possible to have all sides regular: the hexagons are trimmed from rhombuses with the ratio of diagonal lengths the same as the Golden Ratio

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry I meant Kite not rhombus; I'm still unsure if it can be made with a single Kite shape